# Outlook contacts are shown bilingual

Tags: language, microsoft-outlook-2003

Have you ever seen that before? A user have Outlook EN installed on her PC but when she gets in contacts and change the categories, it's shown in french. The "Inbox" is called Inbox instead of "Boite de réception" and I really don't get it why it's bilingual.

It's important to have these categories in english as Outlook and XP is.

Is anyone seen that before?

Comment: I bet 2$, no one knows! Creepy problem!

Comment: Windows and / or Office has installed two language packs: English and French, or there was a previous copy of Outlook that was in French. This doesn't happen by itself.

Answer (score 4):

I have had this problem before. If a user first run Outlook in French, its folders will have the french names even when he runs Outlook in English. The folder names are stored in its exchange mailbox.

In order to reset the folder names, you have to start outlook with the switch /resetfoldernames.

-I know the question is old, I hope my answer will help some people who have the same issue.